# Rails: Execute Javascript (for tracking purposes with Google Analytics) on the server/back-end side ? (whithout a browser)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, server-side, serverside-javascript

Ok, I have been struggling with this a lot... and I have done tons of research and found nothing on google.

Usually to perform the standard google analytics you just dump a little js in the header of the pages you display to your users. No big deal.

But, we are getting more and more advanced tracking with GA, and now we are at the point of tracking our purchases with their recent "eCommerce" module. So in order to do so we want to run some additional JS code when a purchase order has been confirmed and paid.

That sounds easy, but the issue is that the confirmation comes from the payment provider through a notification system (paypal and adyen, they basically work the same). What they do is that they post some data to a form on the site with the confirmation (or refusal) information et boom we can execute some server side code and validate or remove a purchase order.

The issue is now, how in h.ll do execute the Google Analytics JS at that point... because that's the only time when I can guarantee that the order has been fulfilled and that the tracking won't repeat itself (for conversion it's important) if the user refreshed the page ?
The issue here, is that when paypal post to our form, I can generate a response with the GA JS script no problem, but obviously it never gets executed as it's server to server connection, no browser, no JS engine nothing...

Any ideas how I could about this issue, it's really bugging me :(

Thanks,

Alex